# index.php is not redirecting to profile

Tags: php

I am trying to make login portal connected to mysql using php but my index.php is not redirecting to profile.php and showing index.php with blank screen here are my code files.Database is added properly.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
 if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) 
{ 
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd");
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);

    $query = mysql_query('select * from login where password="$password"   AND username="$username"', $connection);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
        header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        exit();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
} 
?>
```

index.php

```
 <?php
 include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) 
{
header("location: profile.php");
exit();
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 //some html code
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
  <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
```

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Please see especially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/367456

Comment: Thanks for the help.The error is    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/login.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/login.php on line 16

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.It is working now:)